# Range.Delete Issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a code that inserts or removes a formatted paragraph based on a drop-down list selection in the same document.
I tested the code separately in a blank document for the insertion and removal, where it worked.
Once I copied it over to my main file, it gives me compile error: Sub or Function not defined, with "Range" selected in the following sub:

```
Dim rngStart, rngEnd As Range

Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("start").Range
Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("end").Range
    
Range(rngStart.End, rngEnd.End).Delete
```

I would be happy with either a solution to the error, or if anyone knows a different approach for inserting and removing a formatted paragraph based on a list-selection which is easier.

Comment: Word doesn't "know" the `Range`-Object without referencing the document. This is different from Excel. You have to use `ActiveDocument.Range(...`

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the whole issue. I was just confused as how it worked in my test file with the exact same syntax. I assume because I ran that from the document object in VBA, and not a module. Good thing to keep in mind, thanks for the explanation!